# Wordpress slider which allows to dynamically change image or text from another plugin

Tags: wordpress, slider

I have developed a plugin for one of my client.

He wants some sections of the website including sliders to be editable. Is there any slider which allows to dynamically edit text / image of a slider programmatically?

We do not want to re-invent the wheel and would like to use any plugin if already available.

Comment: This is off topic: "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow* as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam" Ref [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1):

There are a few slider plugins that you could use. Some are paid, the others have a free version but offer paid features as well. You could try the following:

- **Revolution Slider**
- **Master Slider**

I've had experience using these in multiple projects that I have worked on. These ones are specifically for Sliders and JS based animations etc. but you could possibly build the whole website on it.

**WYSIWYG** editors also have the ability to do what you want to so maybe you could look into that. Examples: **Elementor**, **Page Builder by SiteOrigin**, **Beaver Builder**, etc. I've also had experience using SiteOrigin's editor as it is one of the earliest WP Editor Plugins. Elementor is fairly new but their UI and drag and drop features, IMO, are better or more advanced I would say.

There are tons of them! Just do some research and then come back here if you need any help!

Comment: The plugins mentioned above does not allow programmatically to modify the text in them. I'm looking for plugins which allows to modify them programmatically from another custom plugin which I'm developing.